# Positional and ":" arguments may not both be used

Tags: css, sass

I've been trying to compile a *SCSS* file and the CLI is raising the error saying,

> **Positional and ":" arguments may not both be used.**

The CLI command looks like,

[image]

And the *dir* tree looks like,

[image]

May I know what might be the reason for the error, and how could it be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library can't handle spaces in your file path.  If you remove the space in "2nd year" and "4th sem", it will work.  I hope someone else finds this answer and it saves them the 6 hours I spent before discovering this.  In my case, I have a rails project with dartsass-rails gem running on an Intel Mac, but it sounds like this is an issue at a more core level than the Rails gem.  [Github issue for reference](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1642)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I wonder what could be the problem if there are no spaces in path(s) and the watcher syntax looks like this:
`sass -–no-source-map --style compressed --watch ./styles/tu-app.scss:./tu-public/assets/css/app.css` It still throws `Positional and ":" arguments may not both be used.`